Is there a way I can use CSS to make an Overlay, Reposition close button, and tap anywhere to close Popup box?
I've been able to create most elements on this Popup box, but I find it very difficult to create a dark background Overlay when Popup box is opened. Also to Reposition the Close button to the top-right corner inside the Popup box. And lastly, to tap anywhere outside the Popup box to close Popup. Is there a way to make this happen with CSS?
This is exactly what I want
This is what I've been able to do
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" 
          content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<style>
body {
    background-color: #b0b0b0  !important;
}

.txtrmv {
    position: absolute !important;
    border: none !important;
    font-size: 20px !important;
    color: white !important;
    margin: 0 !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
    text-decoration: none !important;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<br><br><br><br><br>
  <a class="trigger_sb_divi_modal template-pop trigger_template-31291 cboxElement txtrmv"
            data-href="#template-31291">&#x5B;CLICK TO SHOW VIDEO&#x5D;</a>

            <div style="display:none;">
              <div class="sb_divi_modal" id="template-31291">
                <div class="container-popup">
                  <div class="video-wrap">
                    <video src="https://btcscriptsmaker.com/Testvideo1.mp4" controls="" muted="muted"
                    preload="none" class="image fit" style=
                    "width: 100%; visibility: visible;"></video>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

  <script src="https://btcscript.net/assets/js/jqscript.js" type=
  "d9698a347787f66e577c9a00-text/javascript"></script>
  <script src=
  "https://btcscript.net/cdn-cgi/scripts/7d0fa10a/cloudflare-static/rocket-loader.min.js"
  data-cf-settings="d9698a347787f66e577c9a00-|49" defer></script>
</body>
</html>


The tapping anywhere outside to close needs JavaScript. The overlay and reposition, I believe are doable in pure CSS but, in my opinion, it would be way more simple to just do everything in JavaScript.
